# Not sure why in c# I get a totally different TypeCode from a DbType within a SQL command parameter object?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am sure someone is going to shoot this one down in flames.. although the concept from what I can see looks ok...

Basically I am trying to dynamically set a SQL command paramter type and value.  So basically I am:

1. Getting the DbType of the parameter dynamically.. so that part is fine - just referencing like: DbType ParamDBtype = cmd.Parameters[Param1Variable.DbType;
2. Then (stupidly or not!) I am trying to get the Type for within .NET so I can convert value to the correct type (because in my case I am just getting value/pairs as strings.. hence the reason for getting the DbType to *know* what type to convert to)

*So apparently I can do:*
TypeCode ParamDBtypeCode = cmd.Parameters[Param1Variable.DbType.GetTypeCode();

Now the TypeCode can be used when using the Convert statement:

Convert.ChangeType(Param1Value, ParamDBtypeCode)

Well it works.. sort of, because I had a param that was an integer, and the conversion converted that value to an int.. but then I had a param which was an AnsiString DbType, and the TypeCode of that param came back as int16 still???

Anyone had this type of issue, or can point me in a better direction?

Essentially I am trying to assign/convert values to the stored procedure dynamically..

Thanks for any help..

Comment: As far as I know the "value" of a DbParameter is "object" so you don't need to convert anything to assign it as the value of a DbParameter. If the DbParameter already has the type set correctly you're good to go.

Comment: Hey thank you.. I was trying to find out what the param type was from the fieldname in a collection, then assign it correctly.. totally forgot about using SetParameter which allows you simply to pass Field/Value.. so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is `object.GetTypeCode()` on the value - and in the case of a `DbType` the "value" is **the enum**. And the type-code of an enum is simply the enum's underlying type: `int` in this case. It will report `int` for **every** `DbType` - even those that don't exist:

```
var dbtype = (DbType)(-12341);
var typeCode = dbtype.GetTypeCode(); // Int32
```

What you are trying to do has nothing to do with the `DbType`'s `GetTypeCode()`. The problem here is the "*apparently*".

If you really want to map an enum to something else, a `switch` is ideal. It is entirely possible that you will need to provide the mapping yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.. seems like a silly process I was going through.. simply to query the param dbtype from a fieldname in a collection I have.. then of course to assign "that" dbtype to the database.AddInParameter method which takes the param name, type, value... instead I used simply the database.SetParameter method which takes just the param/value... so thanks again for your reply!